# How can i set html in javascript to specific location in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div just like this

```
<div contenteditable="true" >
 Hello this is content editable.... [cursor is blinking here] and more text
</div>
```

How can i set a data where cursor is blinking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) with the `insertHTML` command:

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "the HTML to insert");
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$("div").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 81) {
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<strong>inserted</strong>");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Put your cursor in the relevant location below, then press Ctrl+Q:</p>
<div contenteditable="true">
 Hello this is content editable....  and more text
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sadly this doesn't seem to work on IE11. :-| For cross-browser support, you might look at [Tim Down's `rangy` library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki).

Comment: I am sure that no one uses Internet Explorer sir.

Comment: @mplungjan: Doh! And here I was going for something innocuous. Anything innocuous on OSX?